# Generate n chain from a list

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to generate chain between n codes from a list having codes.
Say for example there are 1000 codes and out of that consider 600 codes form the chain.
Below is one example of connected chain

```
4 -> 5
3 -> 4
2 -> 3
1 -> 2

5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
chainlength=5
```

```
List<Integer> codes = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //[2,4,10,33...1000]
...
for(int i=0;i<600;i++){
 randomcode = random.nextint(codes.size()) //randomly choosing code to get (eg.3)
 codeStart = codes.get(randomcode) //choosing starting path (eg. codes[3]=33)
 maxPathLength = random.nextint(50)
 for(int j=0;j<maxPathLength ;j++){ //based on pathlength generate the chain by choosing random code from codes
 codeEnd = codes.get(randomcode) //(eg. codes[2]=10)
 //33->10
 }
}
```

The chain values does not need to be in sequence but there should be chain connecting all the code based on length

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "codes". Is a "code" supposed to be an edge in the graph? Are cyclical paths valid? The edge directions in your example path are exactly opposite of those defined above it, which one is correct? And finally, the code does not compile because it is missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: Codes basically contain a list of numbers. Based on the length value they should form a chain. yes, the cyclic path can exist. I need to randomly choose a code from a list of codes and form a chain based on the length value.

Comment: So, just so I get this right... Every "code" corresponds to a node in your graph and the attached "list of numbers" contains the IDs of possible successors in the chain? Your `codes` list only contains a single integer per index, that would make the chain completely deterministic (apart from the start location). Should that not be of type `List<List<Integer>>`? Also, was is `items`? That idenfitier is never declared.

Comment: There was a typo mistake just updated the description with comments.

Comment: With the updated question it sounds to me like you just want a sequence of n random values from the input list... But the first part of the question (namely the `4 -> 5` lines) imply that there are some rules which number can come after which.

Comment: Thank you Mario. I was able to solve it myself while i was trying to explain it more. It was simple thing idk why i was trying to make it complicated.

Comment: Sounds like a case of [rubber duck programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) ^^ Anyway, I'm glad to hear you managed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229920/discussion-between-user8866279-and-mario-welzig).

Answer (score 0):

Even after discussing it in the comments, I'm still not entirely sure what you actually want.
My best guess is that you want to generate several random sequences of integers, where all integers in the sequence are from a predefined list.
If this is not the case, please try to explain your goal in a different way.

```java
List<Integer> getRandomSequence(List<Integer> allowedValues, int length, Random random) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(length);
    while(result.size() < length) {
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(allowedValues.size());
        result.add(allowedValues.get(randomIndex));
    }
    return result;
}

// I assume this is the set of valid values
List<Integer> codes = ...; // [2, 4, 10, 33, ..., 1000]
Random random = new Random();

for(int i=0; i < 600; i++) {
    int randomLength = random.nextInt();
    List<Integer> randomChain = getRandomSequence(codes, randomLength, random);
    
    // ... do whatever you need to with the generated chain
}
```